# Quartz Scheduler: Maintain processed files list in the event job metadata

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

We use Quartz scheduler in our application to scan a particular folder for any new files and if there is a new file, then kick off the associated workflow in the application to process it. For this, we have created our custom listener object which is associated with a job and a trigger that polls the file location every 5 min.

The requirement is to process only the new file that arrives in that folder location while ignoring the already processed files. Also, we don't want the folder location to grow enormously with large number of files (otherwise it will slow down the folder scanning) - so at the end of workflow we actually delete the source file.

In order to implement it, we decided to maintain the list of processed files in job metadata. So at each polling, we fetch the list of processed files from the job metadata, compare it against current list of files and if the file is not yet processed - then kick off the associated process flow.

The problem with the above approach is that over the years (and depending on number of files received per day which could be range from 100K per day), the job metadata (that persist list of files processed) grows very large and it started giving us problems with data truncation error (while persisting job metadata in quartz table) and slowness.

To address this problem, we decided to refresh the list of processed files in job metadata with the current snapshot of the folder. This way, since we delete the processed file from folder location at the end of each workflow, the list of processed files remains in limit. But then we started having problem of processing of the duplicate files if it arrives with same name next day.

What is the best approach for implementing this requirement and ensuring that we don't process duplicate files that arrives with same name? Shall we consider the approach of persiting processed file list in the external database instead of job metadata? I am looking for recommended approach for implementing this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I would maybe move the file to a new name (or directory) and then you can check if the file has arrived before.  Decide how many days you want to keep the processed file for.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks! But how and where do I maintain the list of files already processed by the job so that I don't reprocess them if a new file arrives with the same name?

Comment: move the file to somethink like `originalFileName.csv.done`

Comment: `Shall we consider the approach of persiting processed file list in the external database instead of job metadata?` Yes. That's how it's usually done.

Comment: @walen Thanks! We plan to have thousands of such jobs polling on different folder locations in our application. In that case, if we use a single external database table for persisting list of processed files for all those thousands of jobs then the table size may grow huge over the years. Does it has any impact on the quartz performance or is there any design approach that can be followed?

Comment: @Aman as your BBDD table grows, response times may be slower. This can be partially solved by making use of proper indexes and partitioning strategies. Also, you are talking about _years_: does it really make sense to keep this data for so long? Will you ever need to say "_woops, this new file I got has the same name as one I processed 2 years and 4 months ago, better ignore it_"? If it doesn't make sense, you can purge old data from the list / delete rows older than X from the database.

Comment: @Aman also, I think your problem has very little to do with Quartz, but rather with how your whole process is designed. You might get better responses by asking a new question.

Comment: @walen Ok thanks! I just want to confirm that persisting list of processed files in job metadata (in quartz) is never a good idea. Do you agree with it?

Comment: @Aman I cannot agree or disagree with _"persisting list of processed files in job metadata (in quartz) is never a good idea"_. It depends on how big that list is and how frequently you plan on read/write it. What I can say is that using Quartz's tables for persisting non-Quartz data sounds like a lazy hack.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar request recently with our scheduler. If you are on linux, why not using solutions such as [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) ? Other systems may have other ways to monitor file system events.

Our solution was to trigger some file processing at each creation event and then every x days removing the older files (similar to Walen DB suggestion). In that case, the list does not inflate too much and duplicate file can be handled in their own specific case.

(Sorry I do not have the rights to comment yet.)